# Why do people talk about Wizards as though they are common in The Lord of the Rings?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, istari

People say things like:

> "Never trust Wizards"

They talk about Wizards like they're abundant, when in reality there are only five, two of whom (the blue wizards) aren't even known to be active, and the brown wizard prefers animals over people.

Why the discrepancy between the perceived abundance of wizards and the actual, very limited number of wizards?

Comment: Because there are wizards and Wizards...

Comment: Where is the 'never trust wizards' statement made in LoTR?

Comment: @NathanK.Campbell - It's mentioned about four times in LOTR - *"Gildor was silent for a moment. 'I do not like this news,' he said at last. 'That Gandalf should be late, does not bode well. But it is said: Do not meddle in the affairs of Wizards, for they are subtle and quick to anger. The choice is yours: to go or wait.'"*

Comment: @Richard -  I don't discount the premise that the people of Middle Earth know of wizards - I meant specifically - is "never trust wizards" in the text? I wonder if that is being confused with Gimli in the film: "never trust an elf"

Comment: *"now, Pippin my lad, don't forget Gildor's saying - the one Sam used to quote:_ Do not meddle in the at Fairs of Wizards, for they are subtle and quick to anger_.' 'But our whole life for months has been one long meddling in the affairs of Wizards,' said Pippin"*

Comment: "*He did not want information only: he wanted you, quickly, so that he could deal with you in the Dark Tower, slowly. Don't shudder! If you will meddle in the affairs of Wizards, you must be prepared to think of such things. But come! I forgive you. Be comforted! Things have not turned out as evilly as they might.' He lifted Pippin gently and carried him back to his bed. Merry followed, and sat down beside him. Lie there and rest, if you can, Pippin!' said Gandalf."*

Comment: "*Mithrandir, yet with all your subtleties you have not all wisdom. Counsels may be found that are neither the webs of wizards nor the haste of fools.*"

Comment: @NathanK.Campbell - The sentiment seems largely to be based on the prejudices of dwarves but it's notable that the Gondorians and Hobbits have heard the expression before.

Comment: @Richard - all of your quotes are about meddling with wizards, not "never trust a wizard" - I don't think that is in the text (but I don't have my digital copy at the moment) - I think the OP is confusing "never trust an elf" with that particular phrase

Comment: In the real world, we have sayings related to entirely fictional things, including wizards! Like, "she's a wizard with technology". Maybe a better but more controversial example would be "how many angels can dance on the head of a pin?" Or "my guardian angel must have been watching over me". I'd wager that confirmed angel sightings in our world are rarer than wizard interactions in Middle Earth.

Comment: Eg. Julius Caesar was a single person who lived 55 years and yet we have sayings about him. Now imagine if he lived until today, was born at the dawn of time, and there were 5 of him.

Comment: Also, another point - although there were not many kings and emperors in medieval Europe (and elsewhere, really), there are still many sayings about them.

Comment: How is this different from politicians, or kings, or celebrities, or anyone else relatively famous?

Comment: There's only _one_ Donald Trump and yet...

Comment: Why, people in medieval Europe didn't trust witches and sorceres that much either, and yet they were surprisingly uncommon :)

Comment: "Why do people talk about Wizards as though they are common in The Lord of the Rings?" ----

Does this mean to ask "Why do people, in the real world, talk about Wizards so much, even though they are not common in The Lord of the Rings series" or "Why are Wizards discussed so often by characters in Middle-Earth even though there are not many Wizards in the story/land?"  I would argue people in the real world don't talk about Wizards all that much, if that is the question, and that, further, it has no connection to Wizards' appearances or lack there of in any particular story book.

Answer (score 32):

## Book Answer: Tolkien didn't limit the number to five until after writing LotR

Tolkien at points believed that they were many wizards, but with five main ones. His views on various details were not finalized while writing LotR and Hobbit. This can be seen from "*the essay on the Istari*" (written c.1954, *Unfinished Tales*)

> Of this Order, **the number is unknown**, but of those that came to the North of Middle-Earth, where there was most hope (because of the remnant of the Dunedain and of the Eldar who abode there), **the chiefs were five**

As for the movies, your guess is as good as mine. Peter Jackson's Middle-earth is a lot more loosely constructed than Tolkien's Middle-earth and not really so open for analysis.

Comment: But then wouldn't they mean "Sorcerers?" I imagine people must be able to tell the 5 wizards from just human sorcerers.

Comment: Guy turns up, does magic. How do you tell the difference

Comment: Wizards use staffs, have special abilities.

Comment: Plus the wizards are quick to admit there is only 5 of them. Gandalf openly admitted it in the Hobbit.

Comment: @Foreboding Tolkien's views on various details were not finalized while writing LotR and Hobbit.

Comment: @Foreboding - Is there evidence that humans are able to learn magic in Middle-Earth? Elves seem to have natural magical abilities, and Dwarves are able to build some seemingly magical artifacts, but I can't think of any examples of humans doing anything magical offhand.

Comment: In the hobbit, there where mentions of "human sorcerers."

Comment: They originally thought Sauron was one...Radagast called him "The Necromancer."

Comment: @Foreboding: "Gandalf openly admitted it in the Hobbit." — Only in the movies, and the movies aren't real.

Comment: The movies aren't real? What does that mean? They exist, making them real. The movies are based on the books, they should act as if the books aren't there.

Comment: @Foreboding if the question specifically refers to the movies, then you should use the movies tag.

Comment: This still only has some relevance to what I'm discussing. Regardless of whether it was in the movie or not, in the BOOK there are still only five wizards, yet people describe them as being plentiful.

Comment: @Forboding The books say The Mouth of Sauron 'learned great sorcery' in his service to Sauron.

Comment: @Foreboding The books were written before Tolkien limited the number to five.

Comment: @Richard Pointy hat, long cloak, beard

Comment: @redsonja - Having a pointy hat doesn't make you a wizzard.

Comment: @Richard: Right. You have to write "Wizzard" on it.

Comment: @Foreboding Wizards may have defining attributes, but Richard is correct. People broadly categorize what they don't understand to avoid having to think too hard about it. I run into this constantly with the fairly obvious distinction between computer programmer and hardware support tech.

Answer (score 22):

This is largely covered in "[The Unfinished Tales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unfinished_Tales)"

**Basically there were (initially) only 5 of the Istari.**

> *Wizard is a translation of Quenya istar (Sindarin ithron): one of the members of an ‘order’ (as they called it), claiming to possess, and exhibiting, eminent knowledg1e of the history and nature of the World. The translation (though suitable in its relation to ‘wise’ and other ancient words of knowing, similar to that of istar in Quenya) is not perhaps happy, since the Heren Istarion or ‘Order of Wizards’ was quite distinct from the ‘wizards’ and ‘magicians’ of later legend; they belonged solely to the Third Age and then departed, and none save maybe Elrond, Círdan, and Galadriel discovered of what kind they were or whence they came.*

**They spent a lot of time hanging around with important and powerful people**

> *Among Men they were supposed (at first) by those that had dealings with them to be Men who had acquired lore and arts by long and secret study. They first appeared in Middle-earth about the year 1000 of the Third Age, but for long they went about in simple guise, as it were of Men already old in years but hale in body, travellers and wanderers, gaining knowledge of Middle-earth and all that dwelt therein, but revealing to none their powers and purposes. In that time Men saw them seldom and heeded them little.*

**As Sauron's power rose, people paid a hell of a lot more attention to them**

> *But as the shadow of Sauron began to grow and take shape again, they became more active, and sought ever to contest the growth of the Shadow, and to move Elves and Men to beware of their peril. Then far and wide rumour of their comings and goings, and their meddling in many matters, was noised among Men;*

**At which point it was noticed that they weren't aging. This gave them celebrity status since they've now had hundreds of years to become well known**

> *and Men perceived that they did not die, but remained the same (unless it were that they aged somewhat in looks), while the fathers and sons of Men passed away. Men, therefore, grew to fear them, even when they loved them, and they were held to be of the Elven-race (with whom, indeed, they often consorted).*

Answer (score 13):

Its true there are only five wizards, but that can still mean a lot of interactions.

My theory is, the wizards wander everywhere, and meddle in everything... so word gets around.  It would be different if they were living like hermits on mountaintops, but given that they snoop around, interact with lots of people, and also have lived a very long time there's probably a *lot* of incidents where someone interacted/encountered/meddled/decided not to meddle/were warned.  Some of which were likely high profile enough to be famous in song and story (so, very well known).

And the warnings passed up, down, and sideways means that even with only five wizards, everyone has connection with someone who heard something (and subsequently warns others not to meddle with wizards).

In short, even if wizards are uncommon, interactions with them might not be - so the saying becomes widely known.

However, it's just a theory.

Comment: Interactions: it's a real shame there are no lady wizards and no wizardlings

Comment: @RedSonja I agree, that would have been something.

Comment: Didn't Sauron kill off all of the "Younglings" when he declared himself?

Comment: @PatFromCanada Perhaps, but are you sure you're not thinking of Darth Vader?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is really a problem of translation and the limited scope of the tales.  Tolkien uses "Wizard" as a name for the Istari, but there are certainly other people who could reasonably be described as small-w wizards, for instance the Witch-King of Angmar & the Mouth of Sauron.  Denethor would probably qualify as one, as he uses "magic" tools and mental powers, even if those aren't explicitly described.  There are likewise references to past works of wizardry in Gondor, like Amon Hen & Amon Lhaw, so there must have been "wizards" to create them.

Just because we never meet any small-w wizards in the tales doesn't mean they don't exist.  After all, we don't meet many farmers (after leaving the Shire, anyway), carpenters, weavers, garbage collectors, &c, though logically they must exist since we see the results of their activities.